# How can I move window titles to the center of the title bar in 12.10?

Tags: window

By default the window titles are on the left side of the title bar. Is there a way to center the titles?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way, open up your terminal and go to the folder **/usr/share/themes/YourTheme/metacity-1/**

in my case that would be Ambience

`cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/`

in this folder should be a file called **metacity-theme-1.xml**, open this file in your favorite editor, you need sudo rights though!

search for this part

```
<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_normal">
<title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
<title color="#333" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
<title color="#333" x="9" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
<title color="#333" x="11" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
<title color="#dfdbd2" x="10" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>
```

and replace all the x="" numbers with

```
((width - title_width) / 2) max 0
```

so it'll look like this at the end

```
<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_normal">
<title color="#333" x="((width - title_width) / 2) `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
<title color="#333" x="((width - title_width) / 2) `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
<title color="#333" x="((width - title_width) / 2) `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
<title color="#333" x="((width - title_width) / 2) `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
<title color="#dfdbd2" x="((width - title_width) / 2) `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>
```

save the changes, logout and login again, and the titles are centered!

Answer (score 2):

I'd found that Stefan's solution only works in theory, and the title ends up anchoring itself to the left of the titlebar. I'm not sure if my installation is wonky or if the math is wrong, but this is what worked for me:

```
width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0
```

And I also pasted it in the inactive title section. So this part of the file would look like this:

```
<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_normal">
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
  <title color="#dfdbd2" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="draw_title_text_unfocused">
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)+1"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)-1"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
  <title color="#333" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
  <title color="#807d78" x="width/2 - title_width/2 `max` 0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2) `max` 0)"/>
</draw_ops>
```

But I wouldn't have figured this out without Stefan's lead, so kudos to you on that. ;)

Comment: I'm guessing that this used to work in the past and something has changed since because neither this solution or the one below is working for me today 25th June 2015 in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and in my case I needed to edit one of the theme files (Unity.css - Zukimac-com). You need to add this to end of the file:

```
UnityDecoration {
    /* Title settings */
    -UnityDecoration-title-indent: 5px; /* Size property, left indent of the title */
    -UnityDecoration-title-fade: 35px; /* Size property, space of the title that can be faded */
    -UnityDecoration-title-alignment: 0.5; /* Float from 0.0 to 1.0, to align the title - THIS WHAT YOU REELY NEED*/
}
```