# How to center window title text?

Tags: unity, titlebar

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to change the title text of the windows in Unity to the center.

I saw this tutorial: [How can I move window titles to the center of the title bar in 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202802/how-can-i-move-window-titles-to-the-center-of-the-title-bar-in-12-10)

But it does not work. Could you help me?

Comment: Did you try both answers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit one of the theme files (e.g. Unity.css on Zukimac-com). Add this to end of the file:

```
UnityDecoration {
    /* Title settings */
    -UnityDecoration-title-indent: 5px; /* Size property, left indent of the title */
    -UnityDecoration-title-fade: 35px; /* Size property, space of the title that can be faded */
    -UnityDecoration-title-alignment: 0.5; /* Float from 0.0 to 1.0, to align the title - THIS WHAT YOU REELY NEED*/
}
```

You probably have to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.

This is my result:

[image: this]