# How do I move the title to the center of the title bar?

Tags: window, titlebar

Can I move the **window title** to the **center** of the **title bar**?

- When the window is  normal:

  [image]
- And when it's maximized:

  [image]

I just don't know what to do when I look for example here: [How can I move window titles to the center of the title bar in 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202802/how-can-i-move-window-titles-to-the-center-of-the-title-bar-in-12-10)

Well, I hope you will understand what am I looking for.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with **Unity**.

Comment: A better place to look maybe http://askubuntu.com/questions/607006/how-to-center-windows-title-text-ubuntu-14-04/696808 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming. They both point to `-UnityDecoration-title-alignment: 0.0; /* Float from 0.0 to 1.0, to align the title */`

Answer (score 0):

Annnd this is perfect and exactly what i needed! [How to center window title text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607006/how-to-center-window-title-text/696808#696808)
Thanks you DK-Bose!

- It works perfectly in a
  [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cjQC.png) size.
- It seems it doesn't work when it's [maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nng7t.png) (or it's normal i guess).

If you can change the **title bar position to the middle when i maximize the window** i would know.
Anyway thanks!